# Installing Rails 4.2.0.beta1 - Unresolved dependency found during sorting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I've attempted to install Rails 4.2.0.beta1 ([released Aug 20, 2014](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2014/8/20/Rails-4-2-beta1)). I get an error "Unresolved dependency found during sorting." Here are the details:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin13.0]
$ gem -v
2.4.1
$ gem install rails --pre
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::DependencyError)
    Unresolved dependency found during sorting - activesupport (>= 4.0)
(requested by sprockets-rails-3.0.0.beta1)
```

How can I install Rails 4.2.0.beta1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed on RubyGems. Upgrade to at least 2.4.4

Have a look at [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/1062) for more information.

Answer (score 12):

You are using RubyGems 2.4.1:

```
$ gem -v
2.4.1
```

there's a bug with the newest 2.4.1 release of [RubyGems](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems) (the system gem) that makes it difficult to install Rails 4.2.0.beta1. See [Rails issue 16609](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/16609).

You can work around the problem by downgrading to the 2.2.2 version of RubyGems.

```
$ gem update --system 2.2.2
Updating rubygems-update
Fetching: rubygems-update-2.2.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rubygems-update-2.2.2
Installing RubyGems 2.2.2
RubyGems 2.2.2 installed
```

Now you will be able to install Rails 4.2.0.beta1.

If you are using [RVM](https://rvm.io/), and you want to use two different versions of the RubyGems system gem, you'll need to install two different versions of the latest Ruby 2.1.2 release with different [RVM names](https://rvm.io/rubies/named). For example, if you already have Ruby 2.1.2 installed with the newest RubyGems 2.4.1, you can install another version of Ruby 2.1.2, giving it a different name:

```
$ rvm install ruby-2.1.2-oldrubygem
```

RubyGems 2.2.2 is installed by default with the current Ruby 2.1.2 release:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin13.0]
$ gem -v
2.2.2
```

You'll be able to install Rails 4.2.0.beta1.

Comment: I've had rubygems 2.2.2. And the issue was the same.

Comment: Actually my issue is different. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25474135/installing-rails-4-2-0-beta1-bundler-could-not-find-compatible-versions-for-ge

Comment: Issue is now fixed by RubyGems 2.4.4. Please see other answer to this question.