# Installing Rails 4.2.0.beta1 – Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "sprockets-rails"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I've attempted to install Rails 4.2.0.beta1 ([released Aug 20, 2014](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2014/8/20/Rails-4-2-beta1/)). I get an error *Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "sprockets-rails"*. Here are the details:

```
$ bundle update rails
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "sprockets-rails":
  In Gemfile:
    sass-rails (~> 4.0.3) ruby depends on
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0) ruby

    rails (= 4.2.0.beta1) ruby depends on
      sprockets-rails (3.0.0.beta1)
```

How can I install Rails 4.2.0.beta1?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have a [sass-rails gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/sass-rails) in your Gemfile. You need to change the version of *sass-rails* to `'5.0.0.beta1'`. And then run `bundle update sass-rails rails`.

You could find some useful info at [this `sprockets-rails` issue](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/159).

P.S.: Moreover I have the same problem with [`rails_admin`](https://rubygems.org/gems/rails_admin) which I reported [here](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/159#issuecomment-53199017).

Comment: This also solved `File to import not found or unreadable: nprogress` (or any other file in place of `progress`) for me.

Comment: Thanks for this. This should be added to the [Edge guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-4-1-to-rails-4-2) as it's not obvious at all.