# How to upgrade my rails in Mac OS X Yosemite (10.10) to 4.2.0beta2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

Homebrew

My currently rails version is 4.1.6. I want to upgrade to 4.2.0beta2.But i had and error when i types this command

> > gem install rails 4.2.0beta2

i got this error.

> > ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem '4.2.0beta2' (>= 0) in any repository

Anyones know how to fix it ? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a dot between the 0 and beta2.

```
gem install rails 4.2.0.beta2
```

Answer (score 0):

First: You should use ruby RVM.

https://rvm.io/

Second: Take a look on this post:

[Installing Rails 4.2.0.beta1 - Unresolved dependency found during sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25438596/installing-rails-4-2-0-beta1-unresolved-dependency-found-during-sorting)